# Size behaviors differently specified in percent and em/px

Tags: html, css

I have a nav wrapped in header element and same width content frame that should be placed below it.

This is how page looks like when I specify header width in %:

[image: example1]

This is when it's specified in ems or pxs:

[image: example2]

So why just in % it's not working properly?

**HTML:** ("content" class is added only for setting the same color)

```
    <header id="page-header">

        <img id="logo" .../>

        <nav class="content" id="page-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>


    <section class="content" id="content-container">            
        ...
    </section>
```

**CSS:** (just important parts)

```
    /*CSS reset*/
html, body, div, ul, li,
article, footer, header, nav, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

article, footer, header, nav, section {
   display: block;
}
/*end of CSS reset*/

/*header*/

#page-header {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    height:20%; <----- this is where exactly I have a problem 
}

#logo {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 420px;
}
#page-nav
{
    margin-left:30%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
#page-nav a {
    float:left;
    display: block;

    width: 12.5%;
    min-width:100px;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;

    margin: 3em 1.04%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

#page-nav li:first-child a {
    margin: 3em 1.04% 3em 0;
}

#page-nav li:last-child a {
    margin: 3em 0 3em 1.04%;
}



/*content frame*/

#content-container {

    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;

    padding: 2em 6em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage heights are relative to the first `position: relative` container or if none of them are then the html/body tag heights. My guess is you didn't specify a height on parent containers so 20% is not as big as you think it should be.

Have a look at what the parent containers' height is and add a `position: relative` to it. Then set the `#page-header` height percentage to the necessary proportion of the parent container.

If the parent container is the html `<body>` element, then try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Parent container was <body> and indeed this works, thank you very much. I admit that I wouldn't suppose that default body size is NOT 100%... Could you please explain why exactly it works that way?

Comment: Body is a block level element. The HTML spec defines that block level elements take the height of their contents unless otherwise specified.  There are many cases where you definitely wouldn't want block level elements to fill the entire height of their container, such as having divs that each form a "row" inside a column.